# Attribute data disappearing after converting points to line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, geoprocessing, attribute-table, points-to-line

I am currently working on a project strictly in Modelbuilder. I am trying to teach myself how to use it. I don't yet know how to use Python and am still in the early learning stage.

My question has to do with converting points to lines. I have an XY .csv file with latitude and longitude points. I am trying to convert those points to a line, but when I do so using the 'points to lines' tool, the line ends up with no attribute data in the table. All I get is one row with 'polyline M' under shape and no other values.

Here is my current workflow:
[image: Imgur]

The reason that I am trying to keep the attributes is that once I create a line, I am going to measure the distance between each subsequent point on the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool does not carry over source point layer field/attributes.  You will have to apply other tools/methods (e.g. spatial join) to bring over those attributes.

Comment: Spatial join worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Here's what it looks like for anyone else with the same question:

[Imgur Link](http://i.imgur.com/YL7Xlod.png)